# Cannot access STM32F103 device with stlink

Tags: stm32, stm32f1, st-link

I'm trying to access a `STM32F103` device, via a ST-Link V2 programmer, using `st-link` but I am not able to do so. More specifically, when I connect the ST-Link V2 programmer in my usb port the device starts flashing (hopefully, that means the wiring is correct) but when I run `st-info --probe` I'm getting:

```
Found 1 stlink programmers
  version:    V2J29S7
  serial:     21003500140000544334544E
  flash:      0 (pagesize: 0)
  sram:       0
  chipid:     0x0000
  descr:      unknown device
```

*However*, when I run the same command having plugged in a `STM32F429` device (via an on-chip ST-Link programmer), I'm getting a valid response (i.e. `st-link` picks the device up):

```
Found 1 stlink programmers
  version:    V2J36S26
  serial:     066DFF555071494867053245
  flash:      2097152 (pagesize: 16384)
  sram:       262144
  chipid:     0x0419
  descr:      F42x/F43x
```

I even tried building the latest `st-link` from Github (`develop` branch) but am getting the same response.

Some details about versions/OS:
`st-info --version` reports => `v1.7.0`,
OS => `Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS`

Any thoughts on what might be going on? Does version `1.7` not support this device? - Thanks

Comment: You could see if it works with STM32CubeIDE or STM32CubeProgrammer. That might clarify if it is a hardware problem, or an issue with the `st-link` software.